# Django PostgresqlJSONField custom decoder

Tags: json, django, postgresql, django-models

Providing a custom encoder is easy, as we can give set the encoder parameter, but using a custom decoder seems not possible. How would I go about using a custom decoder for Django PostgresqlField?

As example,
we have an Custom JSON Encoder:

```
class JSONObjectEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    class JSONEncodable:
        def encode(self):
            raise NotImplementedError()

    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o,JSONObjectEncoder.JSONEncodable):
            return o.encode()
        return super().default(o)
```

If we want to encode a class it would be:

```
class Parameter(JSONObjectEncoder.JSONEncodable):
   def encode(self):
       return #something
```

and the postgresfield would look like this:

```
params = PostgressJSONField(encoder=JSONObjectEncoder)
```

Now every object that implements JSONEncodable, can be decoded into json.
But once we have the JSON comming from the database, I want to automatically encode it into the parameter class.

Comment: Can you share your attempt at doing this or let us know what you are trying to encode/decode

Comment: psycopg2 doesn't give a nice way to pass a decoder on a query. It does give you the option of setting a custom loads method on [the DB connection itself](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.register_json). This may not be suitable though

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with by myself is using a normal textfield, and using the standard json functions. Hereby you do lose the ability to query the field, but for simple usecases it does the job.

```
class JSONField(models.TextField):
    description = _("JSON")
    def __init__(self,*args,encoder=None,decoder=None,**kwargs):
        super(JSONField, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder

    def to_python(self, value):
        """Convert our string value to JSON after we load it from the DB"""

        if value == "":
            return None
        try:
            return json.loads(value,cls=self.decoder)
        except ValueError as e:
            __log__.error("used ' instead of \"?")
        return value

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, context):
        return self.to_python(value)

    def get_db_prep_save(self, value, connection):
        if value == "":
            return ""
        if isinstance(value, str):
            return value
        try:
            dump = json.dumps(value,cls=self.encoder)
            return dump
        except Exception as e:
            __log__.error(e)
        return ""
```